# CSS works fine in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, however fails in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a website with a group of friends for a community based site focused on educational programs. As the title states, Internet Explorer is the only web browser that our CSS doesn't seem to work.

Here's a link to the website: 
http://new.lexingtoncommunityed.org/

The main offenders are within the home.php page and the programs pages. The spacing is completely off from what it looks on other browsers.

We're considering making a new IE stylesheet, however we aren't sure of the difficulties nor practices that we have to do in converting the css over to be compatible with IE, including testing compatibility with other browsers as well. Is it worth it to rebuild the CSS using a framework instead?

Comment: AFAIK, IE is dead.

Comment: @AllDani.com No, IE is not dead.

Comment: IE is dead, but the problem with the site is easily fixable. See my answer.

Comment: @Steve Li, which IE version are you talking about? is it IE9, IE10, IE11, or do you mean Edge?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, I like your attitude. Easy fix or graceful degradation are sure better that won't fix. Even when IE is dying, in my work we still have to support some enterprise customers that are still using IE10 and IE9.

Comment: @elfan IE11, though users of the site may have varying versions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the margin-bottom to the body instead of the inner elements will fix the problem for IE, and should not adversely affect the other browsers. Just add `margin-bottom: 200px` to the `body` in the CSS, and it should work for IE as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works for the home page, however in the Classes page (under programs) the footer is still in a weird position given the grid layout of the class categories. The LEXPLORATIONS page also has the footer in an off position. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Yes. On the LEXPLORATIONS page, it's because the `<footer>` is inside of `<div id="main">` instead of after it, as it is on the other pages. To solve the problem with the footer moving, change the `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` in the CSS.

Comment: Hm when I set the position to fixed it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Really? If you set `position: fixed;` it should always be on the bottom of the page, regardless of how much content there is (as for the `Class`-page). You still need to redo the HTML for the `LEXPLORATIONS`-page, since that is the problem on that page.

Comment: Ah I see. By setting the position to fixed on the class page however, when scrolling the footer stays put at the bottom, as what setting the position to fixed is meant to do. Is there a way to fix the footer without having it stuck to the bottom when scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it worth it to rebuild the CSS using a framework instead?

## No.

On January 12th, 2016, Microsoft [wrote](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support):

> After January 12, 2016, Microsoft will no longer provide security updates or technical support for older versions of Internet Explorer.

Also:

> **Q:** How long will the most current version of Internet Explorer remain supported?
>
> **A:** Internet Explorer is a component of the Windows operating system and the most current version will continue to follow the specific support lifecycle policy for the operating system on which it is installed.
> Internet Explorer 11 will be supported for the life of **Windows 7**, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.
> To find the support lifecycle dates for all operating systems, search the Support Lifecycle Database [here](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/).

So, though it still 'works', it's dying. Officially.
Of course, you *can* change your CSS to work with it, but why? It's own makers are saying "Don't use it"!

Source: [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure the height of the `footer`, you can add `margin-bottom` to the body.
Else you should use js to get the height of the footer, and add it to the `margin-bottom` of the body

Or you can do like this.
If the content's height is too short, you should add `min-height` to body.

```css
html{height:100%;}
body{min-height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;color:#fff;}

.header{background-color: #ccc;}
.main{padding-bottom:100px;background-color: #999;}
.footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100px;background-color: #333;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    Top
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>LCE is a self-sustaining, integral part of the Lexington Public Schools, committed to bringing lifelong learning to all. We provide practical, creative, and fun educational opportunities at reasonable cost. We seek to provide the best teachers and the most engaging subjects.

Our programs are open to all adults and young adults, regardless of residency. We also offer an extensive summer children's program called LEXPLORATIONS, which offers creative and academic classes.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    info@lexingtoncommunityed.org 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```